# Why is super class constructor always called

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass, default-constructor

I have the following 2 classes

```
public class classA {
    classA() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class classB extends classA {
    classB() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

and then running

## 1

```
classA c = new classB();
```

or

## 2

```
classB c = new classB();
```

always gives

```
A
B
```

Why is this happening? At first glance, in either scenario, I would assume that only the `classB` constructor would be called and thus the only output would be

```
B
```

but this is clearly wrong.

Comment: Note that for classes you should use the Java standard naming convention with names like `ClassA` and `ClassB`.  Names starting with lower case characters indicate variables.

Comment: "I would assume that only the `classB` constructor would be called and thus the only output would be `B`" But `classB`'s constructor prints `A`...

Comment: @totymedli thanks for pointing that out. I had them switched

Comment: As far as I know in the world of mammals ancestor is constructed usually before its descendants.. Probably the Java original designers mimic the same behavior.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen They are also typically used for non-constructor methods.

Answer (score 57):

That is how Java works. The constructors of the parent classes are called,  all the way up the class hierarchy through `Object`, before the child class's constructor is called.

Quoting from [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

> With `super()`, the superclass no-argument constructor is called. With `super(parameter list)`, the superclass constructor with a matching parameter list is called.
>
> > **Note:** ***If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass***. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. `Object` does have such a constructor, so if `Object` is the only superclass, there is no problem.
>
> If a subclass constructor invokes a constructor of its superclass, either explicitly or implicitly, you might think that there will be a whole chain of constructors called, all the way back to the constructor of `Object`. In fact, this is the case. It is called *constructor chaining*, and you need to be aware of it when there is a long line of class descent.

Answer (score 9):

Super class constructor is always called during construction process and it's guaranteed that super class construction is finished before subclass constructor is called. This is the case for most if not all the object oriented language. You could explicitly call super class constructor with parameter if you don't want to invoke the default constructor; otherwise such call is automated by compiler.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in both statements in terms of objects being constructed so you see same out put.

Just using a *different reference type on left hand side* while constructing same objects using `new` is not going to make any difference as far as object creation and constructor chaining is concerned.

Whatever difference is there among two of your statements is after objects get created.