# Super constructor call order

Tags: java, control-flow-graph

In the following example which constructor of the class `U` calls invokes the `super` constructor? The one without arguments or the one with one argument ?

```
public class T{
    T(){
        System.out.println("T()");
    }
       public static void main(String[] args){
        new U();
    }
}

class U extends T{
    U(){
        this(2);
        System.out.println("U()");
    }
    
    U(int x){
        System.out.println("U(int x)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the question you have the code, you can debug/run It and seems a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/34488527/1511193

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is super class constructor always called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488484/why-is-super-class-constructor-always-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first constructor `U()` calls the second constructor `U(int x)` via the `this(2)` call.

The second constructor `U(int x)` calls the super class constructor `T()` implicitly.

Which means both `U` constructors call the super class constructor, either directly or indirectly.